# Delete selected rows in dataset

Tags: c#

I'm having some issues with deleting selected rows in a datatable. I've followed several other examples on this site but they all lead to all of my data being erased from the database. Any suggestions on how to delete selected rows that is being pulled in from a database file?

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Docket\Database1.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        string strSQL = "Select * from login";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
        da.Update(dt);
    }
```

Edit: Updated code that shows the items being removed from the table. I should have clarified that I'm wanting to remove any selected options from the datagrid AND the database, the above code only removes them from what the user sees on the screen. I'm guessing my string that selects everything in the database needs to be modified but I'm not sure what to modify it to say.

Comment: Are you trying to delete everything from the login table (your query selects all rows), or just selected rows. You could modify the original query to select the rows you want, or inspect the data before deleting.

Comment: I doubt that this runs at all. `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` returns a [`DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). If you loop it in a `foreach` you get a `DataGridViewRow` not a `DataRow`. You could cast the `DataBoundItem` to `DataRow`.

Comment: Also, do you want to remove the rows from the table or do you want to delete them from database, third option: remove them from the `DataGridView`. What do you want to do at all?

Comment: My goal is to remove them from the database entirely. The updated code shows them removed from the datagrid but not the database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your foreach to:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
 {
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
 }
```

Comment: I tried using the (item.Index) and it wouldn't accept .Index so I'm assuming that I've written the foreach statement incorrectly. 
Wouldn't this option just remove the selected item from the datagrid and not from the database?

Comment: Change `DataRow` to `DataGridViewRow` and you'll get my plus.

Comment: Wouldn't this just remove the row from the datagrid - not delete them from the datatable.

Comment: @paul: it seems that this is what OP actually wants to do: _"...deleting selected rows in a datatable..."_ So he doesn't want to delete but remove them.

Comment: :) I focused on _"how to delete selected rows that is being pulled in from a database file"_ and assumed it was deleting from the database table.